# .csv upload not working in Amazon Web Services Machine Learning - AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, machine-learning

I have uploaded a simple 10 row csv file (S3) into AWS ML website. It keeps giving me the error, 
    "We cannot find any valid records for this datasource."

There are records there and Y variable is continuous (not binary). I am pretty much stuck at this point because there is only 1 button to move forward to build Machine Learning. Does any one know what should I do to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I used .txt file instead of .csv. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have been able to upload .csv files to S3 created on my own is by downloading an existing .csv file from my S3 server, modifying the data, uploading it then changing the name in the S3 console.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the first few lines of contents of the .csv file? I am able to upload my own .csv file along with a schema that I have created and it is working. However, I did have issues in that Amazon ML was unable to create the schema for me.

Also, did you try to save the data in something like Sublime, Notepad++, etc. in order to get a different format? On my mac with Microsoft Excel, the CSV did not work, but when I tried LibreOffice on my Windows, the same file worked perfectly.